# Return RedirectToAction with return Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am saving a form using html.beginform  and I return RedirectToAction("Index") after saving the data in database. My problem is that. After it is redirected to the same page , It brings in Url ::

`http://localhost:2291/Mycontroller/Index` which is not correct. Actually I want to maintain it's state as this url originally was

```
http://localhost:2291/Mycontroller/Index?ID=135
```

actually When I click on edit button in the grid, It goes to this controller and opens this page with the url::

```
http://localhost:2291/Mycontroller/Index?ID=135
```

after saving the data , as I am using Html.Beginform due to file upload control, On redirecttoAction, It redirects to a new Indexpage
 `http://localhost:2291/Mycontroller/Index` and that is incorrect.It should be ::

```
http://localhost:2291/Mycontroller/Index?ID=135
```

as I am currently in this page and updating a record.

How to achieve this. I am using MVc 4.0

Comment: Have you tried not redirecting and instead just returning the view: `return View();`?

Comment: Actually didn't put that much thought into it... It's doing a postback, the id will get removed. You should consider sending the data with AJAX, without using a form. Then your page will not "redirect".

Comment: Actually my save method is  http://localhost:2291/Mycontroller/SaveReferralDetails in Html.BeginForm so, it returns this url if I use returnview

Comment: I can'nt use Ajax because there is a file upload control

Comment: Try like this - `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = YourIdVariable });`, then it will redirect to the Url - /MyController/Index/222

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in your id value as an argument in RedirectToAction e.g.:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ID = 135 });
```

This will generate the URL

```
http://localhost:2291/Mycontroller/Index?ID=135
```

As desired.